# "Cascade" Databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

i am beginner in wpf and i want to help with this piece of XAML code.

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Elements[person]}" >
       <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="headerPhone" Binding="{Binding Element[phone].Value}">
             <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Name="headerPhoneCStyle">
                   <Style.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Element[phone].Attribute[changed].Value}" Value="yes">
                      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
      </DataGridTextColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Is there some way how to reduce this:

```
Binding="{Binding Element[phone].Attribute[changed].Value}"
```

To just something like this:

```
Binding="{Binding Attribute[changed].Value}"
```

Comment: `Binding="{Binding Attribute[changed].Value}"` is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you would need to change the `DataContext` of the items. Currently, your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property is data bound to the `Elements[person]` object... this *must* be a collection of some kind and so the `DataContext` of each item is set to *an element from this collection*.

It's hard to tell the exact structure of your data class because you didn't show us [[*you should always show all the relevant code*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)], but if your `Binding` works, then it seems as though each item has an indexed property named `Element` in it. Now if you want to data bind directly with the object that is returned when using the index `phone`, you can just add that to the `ItemsSource Binding` instead:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Elements[person].Element[phone]}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="headerPhone" Binding="{Binding Value}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Name="headerPhoneCStyle">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Attribute[changed].Value}" 
                            Value="yes">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

However, if `Elements[person].Element[phone]` is *not* a collection, there is not much point in using a `DataGrid` to display it... if it *is* a collection, then this *should* work just fine. Let me know how you get on. Also, you should see the [Property Path Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [`Binding.Path` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) pages on MSDN for more help with `Binding.Path` syntax.